# discord.py how can I use the result of a form to change someones nickname?

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm using discord.py rewrite and I want to get input from a user via a form. The questions would be something along the lines of "First Name? Last Name?" and I want to change the users nickname according to the results of the form. Does anyone know how I can do this or if this is possible?

Comment: Are you talking about a webpage form? Or like a questionnaire?

Comment: What form?, where from?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.

Comment: "Is there any way" is a non-issue for Stack Overflow. Since you're on a general-purpose computer that is barely short of a Turing machine, the answer is almost always "yes". The follow-up question, "How do I do it?", is too broad for Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Given a discord.Member object, you can use `member.edit(nick=new_nick)`. If your form is through messaging on discord, it should be relatively easy to get the member object. If your form is through google forms, you may have to send submitted answers to a spreadsheet and use the google sheets API to access the information. If you do that, one of the questions will have to ask for a discord ID or some other identifier so that the bot can define the member object.